# PHP CSV Output - How to add two rows?

Tags: php, csv

Hellos!

Alessandro Minoccheri already helped me alot with this code, but I've got one more problem. The CSV file is a output file from powershell (get-aduser) - it is comma seperated.

As first this is the csv content:

```
#TYPE Selected.Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser
name,"officephone"
firstname, lastname,"+49 1234 555 134"
firstname, lastname,"+49 1234 555 242"
firstname, lastname,"+49 1234 555 338"
firstname, lastname,"+49 1234 555 149"
```

And this is the code for the moment:

```
$lineCount = 0;
while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
if ($lineCount > 1) {
    echo "<tr class='departmenttext'>";
    foreach ($line as $key => $cell) {
        if ($key == 1) {
           $cell = substr($cell, -3);
           echo '';
        }
        echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";

        if ($key == 1) {
            echo "</tr>\n";
        }
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
$lineCount = $lineCount + 1;
}
```

it displays a CSV file in one row. Means

```
Name1 Phone1
Name2 Phone2
Name3 Phone3
Name4 Phone4
```

But as it is sometimes very long I would be in need of the following:

```
Name1 Phone1    Name5 Phone5
Name2 Phone2    Name6 Phone6
Name3 Phone3    Name7 Phone7
Name4 Phone4
```

But as I just got one export function "htmlspecialchars($cell) I don't know how to separate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to wrap the file like you want, but the alternative is to put entries side by side...

```
$lineCount = 0;
fgetcsv($f);
fgetcsv($f);
while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
    if ( count($line)<2 )   {
        break;
    }
    if ($lineCount % 2 == 0) {
        echo "<tr class='departmenttext'>";
    }
    echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($line[0].','.$line[1]) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars(substr($line[2],-3)) . "</td>";

    if ($lineCount % 2 == 1) {
        echo "</tr>\n";
    }
    $lineCount = $lineCount + 1;
}
if ($lineCount % 2 == 1) {
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't have a problem with that, but when I am using that code I am not seeing anything. The csv file is an output file from powershell and it is comma seperated. Maybe that's the reason why?

Comment: Can you put some sample lines in your original question, I will check it.

Comment: I wasn't skipping the first two lines, so I've done that before going into the loop.

Comment: You may have to adjust the fields it's displaying as well, $line[0] and [1] are the name and $line[2] is the phone number.

Comment: Ive tried it. Its looking really great. Okay,  At the moment it does Name1 and Name2 in one line and then Name3 and Name4 in the next line. Is it also possible to display it like Name1, Name2 and so on in one row and then at the other side the next beginning? Because I do have it sorted by alphabetic name so that there is a list side by side. If it is not possible, well, then it is so...... but where exactly I have to input that "$cell = substr($cell, -3);" back again? because the phone number is the full one and I am just in need of the last three digits :\

Comment: Just updated the 2 echo lines, they should be closer to what your after.

Comment: Hey Nigel,
Thanks a lot for your help. it worked perfectly after some short edits. thank you very much for your patient and support. I'm marking your answer as solution

Answer (score 0):

```
First of all you have to decide that how much line you want in one bunch. and according to that number, You need to start a new raw in loop.

for example, if you want to show up to 10 line in one bunch, like

you need something like

if($key%10 == 0){
    echo "</tr><tr class='departmenttext'>";
    echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
}
```

Comment: So in this case I am going to display my largest list, count it and set that as total number as one list? an auto of 50% is not possible to do? like a counter and then just display half of it?

Comment: Do you mean using CSS ?

Comment: nah, not by css, by any math count function maybe.

Comment: Ok, than you can do something like this way.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can do something like this way

if($key%count($line) == 0){
    echo "</tr><tr class='departmenttext'>";
    echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
}

Here I have divided it by total number of line so that it can be calculate 50% of your line.
```